# Twitter Location Feature Does not work outside Major Countries using the web interface

Tags: twitter, geolocation

I tried updating my status using twitter.com and I cannot get the location feature attached to tweet again. Last month I was in North America and geo-location worked great. Now I have moved for vacation to the Caribbean (Trinidad and Tobago) and I cannot get it to work. First time it tried to find it, resulted in location not available.

In the settings Tweet Location is set to Add a location to my tweets.

Of course on geo-aware apps like Tweetie and so forth I can get it to work. I tried setting it manually using a Command Tweet

```
SET LOCATION trinidad and tobago
```

No luck. Is there a Solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the location awareness help pages on Twitter:

http://twitter.zendesk.com/forums/26810/entries/78525

Right at the bottom it says that it only works in the US right now.

Comment: ah hah . :( ... well I guess its Tweetie for Life then.